# Chrome devTools detects remote device but not active Chrome tabs and offers no link

Tags: android, google-chrome, debugging

I have been struggling to figure out how to debug a webpage on mobile. Previously I have had no difficulty with this, but the last time I tried was maybe a year ago and some things have changed. I have an Android device with version 9 installed and Chrome stable 80. On the connected laptop I'm trying to use to debug, I have Ubuntu 19.10 and Chrome stable 80 installed.

The first thing I notice that's different is the disapearance of the remote devices tab in DevTools. Instead I am directed to `chrome://inspect/#devices` This is not documented in the [relevant guide from google](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging) ([an issue](https://github.com/google/WebFundamentals/issues/8545) has already been filed). As such I don't know if the functionality is identical and therefore not part of my problem  of if the move represents an important change that I am failing to understand in trying to debug my webapp.

Second. I go to the new devices page and find my device listed, great! The problem is that I can't figure out how to do anything with it. In the old remote devices tab there was a way to show the currently active webviews and chrome tabs and debug them. Now I see nothing of the sort.

[image: Chrome devices page]

I want to know what to do to get access to my browser on the device to debug. I have usb debugging active and connected. `adb devices` reports:

```sh
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
a6f8aef4    device
```

I have searched far and wide on the internet with no luck. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29942627/chrome-remote-debugging-shows-device-but-not-inspect-link) is very similar but is in the context of Android 4.0 and trying to debug an APP instead of a chrome tab.

What am I missing?